# using trap to close one program when another is closed

Tags: bash, script, bash-scripting

Ok...here's my goal....I use dwm, so normally I have no need for a compositing manager. That being said, there are times when I would like to have it running temporarily. There are times when I want to have a browser open, with lxterminal floating on top. I'm a relative new-comer to scripting, meaning I do know how to accomplish simple tasks.

What I want to do is write a script that starts xcompmgr automatically when I start lxterminal, then exit xcompmgr when I close lxterminal. I'm told using "trap" is the proper way to get this done; I just don't know how to write it.

Here's what I got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
xcompmgr &
lxterminal
# here's where I get stumped


done
```

can anyone help me with this little script?

Comment: @kenorb That's scripting not really programming. Scripting questions are welcome on [su].

Comment: I apologize. This was my first post on this forum. It seems to work a little differently than most of the others. I think I've got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
xcompmgr &
xcmpid=$!
lxterminal
kill $xcmpid
```